# jsonnet import local variable from another jsonnet file

Tags: jsonnet

I have a `a.libsonnet` file:

```
local panel = {
  new(...)::{... },
  createFromConfig(config)::
    this.new(),
};

local config = std.extVar('config');
panel.createFromConfig(config)
```

It seams if i only do in another file `local panel = import 'a.libsonnet'` will also execute `panel.createFromConfig(config)`
Is there a way I can only import panel?

Answer (score 1):

I think your original question is somewhat truncated (that strange 1st line).

In any case, below may implement what I *guess* you're after:

### file: `a.libsonnet`

```jsonnet
// a.libsonnet
{
  local this = self,
  new(config):: { initWhat: config },
  createFromConfig(config)::
    this.new(config),
}
```

### file: `foo.jsonnet`

```jsonnet
// foo.jsonnet
local panel = import 'a.libsonnet';

local config = std.extVar('config');
panel.createFromConfig(config)
```

### CLI output

```shell
$ jsonnet --ext-str config=Foo foo.jsonnet
{
   "initWhat": "Foo"
}
```